# Cannot open shared object file when using D compiler

Tags: executable, dynamic-linking

I had [ldc2](https://bitbucket.org/prokhin_alexey/ldc2/wiki/Home) and [gdc](https://bitbucket.org/goshawk/gdc/wiki/Home) compiled from source and working up until a month ago.  Nothing has changed, except I can't remember the variable(s) I would set in the terminal to get ldc2 and gdc to work.

I get the following errors when trying to compile D source code; with gdc (`$ /home/Code/D/gdc/Bin/usr/local/bin/gdc -o t4 t4.d`):
`/home/Code/D/gdc/Bin/usr/local/bin/../libexec/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.4.5/cc1d: error while loading shared libraries: libmpfr.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

With ldc2 (`/home/Code/D/ldc2/bin/ldc2 -o t4 t4.d`):
`/home/Code/D/ldc2/bin/ldc2: error while loading shared libraries: libconfig++.so.8: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

I can't remember if it was just an addition to PATH or something to DFLAGS.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you can't even run the compiler executable, because it can't find the libraries it needs. `gdc` is looking for `libmpfr.so.1` and `ldc2` is looking for `libconfig++.so.8`.

If these libraries are still present on your system, perhaps in `/home/Code/D/gdc/Bin/usr/local/lib`, you can add that directory to the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable (on most unices; on Mac OS X, the variable is called `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH`).

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/Code/D/gdc/Bin/usr/local/lib gdc …
```

You may want to write wrapper scripts to run `gdc` and `ldc2`, or put this in your `~/.profile`:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/Code/D/gdc/Bin/usr/local/lib
```

If these libraries were in `/usr/lib` and disappeared in a system upgrade, you'll have to either restore the required versions, or recompile the D tools for the new versions of the libraries.